# Add missing columns to an R table

Tags: r

Given this sample data:

```
x = 1:12; names(x) = LETTERS[1:length(x)]
y = c('A','C','E','F','J','E','K','L','E','L','F','A','E')
```

When I do `table(y)` I get:

```
A C E F J K L 
2 1 4 2 1 1 2
```

How do I expand that to include zero entries for all the other column headings in `x`? In other words the output I'm after is:

```
A C E F J K L B D G H I
2 1 4 2 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0
```

(unsorted as shown there, or sorted, I don't mind.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a factor:

```
table(factor(y, levels = names(x)))
# A B C D E F G H I J K L 
# 2 0 1 0 4 2 0 0 0 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of a way to do this with `table`, but it's a pretty simple one-liner regardless:

```
sapply(names(x), function(name) {sum(y == name)})
```

Output:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L 
2 0 1 0 4 2 0 0 0 1 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks! I gave the tick to flodel, as it best answers the asked question, but this was the code I _actually_ wanted (because I needed a named vector not a `table`, and `as.vector(mytable)` seems to lose the names).

Comment: @DarrenCook, you can do `c(mytable)` to convert to a integer vector and preserve the names.